# Multiple threads accessing the database simultaneously

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I am working on making a downloader in `Android`. To allow the database to be shared across multiple activities I created a singleton instance of the `WritableDatabase`.

Each thread that downloads some content needs to write to the database how much data, in total, has been downloaded. Since multiple threads will be accessing this instance, do I need to use a `synchronized` code block while entering the values into the database ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is safe to use `SQLiteDatabase` from multiple threads, but by default each operation will block others. To enable concurrent updates, use `enableWriteAheadLogging`. Read more at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#enableWriteAheadLogging()

Answer (score 1):

It's like the Readers/Writers problem, there's no problem when multiple threads are reading from the Database, but when they're trying to write, you must use a synchronized block to allow a thread-safe operation.